# how to forward a request from flask to another api app

Tags: python, flask

I want to create a dynamic handler, which can process all requests and forward them to other apps based on the database [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1muY.png)

Answer (score 1):

After the route check in the function you can further request

> from flask import request
>
> rule = request.url_rule
>
> if 'antitop' in rule.rule:
> # request by '/antitop'
>
> elif 'top' in rule.rule:
> # request by '/top'